# Are "proof-of-concept" apps allowed in the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

My company deals with a specific technology and we're looking to submit a limited functionality proof-of-concept app to the App Store as a sort of advertisement of our experience and capabilities. Is an app like this likely to be rejected?

**Edit**: my original question above sounds a little subjective and opinion based, so to clarify: I'm looking for case history or documentation from apple that clarifies this scenario.

Comment: Does the app as is provide any value to the user?

Comment: @patrix that is subjective. I suppose the most succinct answer is: Not to the "average" user, but Yes, for some.

Comment: Why not create it and submit it and see what happens?

Comment: @TobyAllen because development time costs money, and it's cheaper to ask first to double check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a great many apps which offer very little in terms of functionality, and essentially advertise a company and accessories (such as the Jabra and Plantronics apps) and some which just display information about select services of the company.

There are also many apps which require specific infrastructures to be in place for an organisation to even use the app which offer no functionality for the average user, such as Good for Enterprise, or Excitor DME.

As long as it complies with the submission guidelines, there's no reason Apple would reject it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should look at alternatives like [TestFlightApp](https://testflightapp.com/).
It offers you a platform where you can set-up a test version of your app and the platform allows you to make several and extensive conclusions.

Comment: We don't want to test an app. We already have enterprise distribution set up. What we want is a publicly available concept app that can be found by users who aren't specifically targeted or specified. TestFlightApp doesn't fit this need at all.